# Can multiple threads execute the same instance methods in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, race-condition

If we have a instance method that makes an api call and doesn't modify any instance attributes, can it be executed simultaneously in multiple threads, without causing any race condition?

Since the method I am executing doesn't involves any modification of instance attributes, there shouldn't be any issues of race condition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - Python support multithreading and it can be executed avoiding race conditions.

[multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

However **Race conditions** can occurs. Python Interpreted (GIL) - allowing only one thread to execute python bytecode at a time.

Avoiding race conditions by those techniques:

- Thread-Safe data structures (Queue)
- Locking Mechanisms
- Simple operations

---

```
#Create two process objects
process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=count_numbers, args=("Process 1",))
process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=count_numbers, args=("Process 2",))

#Start the processes
process1.start()
process2.start()

#Wait for both processes to finish
process1.join()
process2.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there's a question about thread safety, it's never really about which threads enter which methods. It's really about which threads access which *data.* If the instance method in question never touches any data that are shared between threads, then it's perfectly safe to concurrently call it from more than one thread without synchronization. On the other hand, if two *different* methods that are concurrently called can access the same shared data, then those *do* need synchronization.